# how can i sort a list of nested dicttionary in python?

Tags: python

you can considered the following list

```
[{'mesa': {'url': 'https://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/mesa/mesa.git', 'commit': 'a6e212440278df2bb0766a5cf745935d94809144', 'location': 2}}, {'macros': {'url': 'https://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/xorg/util/macros.git', 'commit': '39f07f7db58ebbf3dcb64a2bf9098ed5cf3d1223', 'location': 7}}, {'drm': {'url': 'https://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/mesa/drm.git', 'commit': '19c4cfc54918d361f2535aec16650e9f0be667cd', 'location': 1}}]
```

i want to sort the list of dictionary by the key 'location'

Thanks

Comment: `sort` and `sorted` both have a `key` parameter. If you Google you should be able to answer your own question in a minute or so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method, passing in the appropriate `key=` parameter. For example:

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0]['location'])
```

Complete program:

```
from pprint import pprint
l=[{'mesa': {'url': 'https://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/mesa/mesa.git', 'commit': 'a6e212440278df2bb0766a5cf745935d94809144', 'location': 2}}, {'macros': {'url': 'https://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/xorg/util/macros.git', 'commit': '39f07f7db58ebbf3dcb64a2bf9098ed5cf3d1223', 'location': 7}}, {'drm': {'url': 'https://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/mesa/drm.git', 'commit': '19c4cfc54918d361f2535aec16650e9f0be667cd', 'location': 1}}]

l.sort(key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0]['location'])
pprint(l)
```